# Open Active Directory w/ Button. VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making a generic program that will allow me and my co-workers to use a windows form to quick launch applications we use daily. One of the programs is Active Directory Administrative Center. Another would be Active Directory Users and Computers. We use both for different reasons. The code is below to open these.

```
Imports System.IO 
Imports System
Imports System.Text 
Public Class form_UI

 Private Sub btnAD1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAD1.Click
        Dim ad1 As String = "C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc"
        Process.Start(ad1)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnAD2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAD2.Click
        Dim ad2 As String = "C:\Windows\System32\dsac.exe"
        Process.Start(ad2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am missing something. When I click on Users and Computer `btnAD1` it loads fine, using that path. What happens when I click on the Administrative Center `btnAD2`I have an error stating that it does not exist, but it does, and in that file path (can't tell you how many times I verified that). Why it opens AD: Users and Computers and not AD: Administrative Center has me stuck. I have tried different combinations of paths, different ways to open the file. Different `Imports` (SystemConfigeration). But nothing is working. I have a feeling it is something to do with it needing admin rights to open (it prompts when .exe is clicked). But, again, I am not sure.
When I run to open "C:\Windows\System32\dsac.exe", it works. In explorer, run, cmd.

I need some help, any help. Much would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system? If so, `C:\Windows\System32` appears to be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` in 32-bit applications. Try compiling your application as `x64` or `AnyCPU`.

Comment: Also, what happens if you try `C:\Windows\Sysnative\dsa.msc` instead?

Comment: @VisualVincent When I change `"C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc"` to `C:\Windows\Sysnative\dsa.msc` I get an error stating "The remote procedure call failed". And I am compiling my application as AnyCPU but not as x64. Though I am attempting that right now

Comment: @VisualVincent Yep.. Configuring the platform to x64 did it. Going to test it on a couple more computers for verification. But I think that was it! :D

Comment: Glad to hear. Though AnyCPU would probably be the best if you want your application to work on both 32 and 64-bit systems.